# speechSynthesis.getVoices()で使用可能な音声を取得できない

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

chromeでWeb Speech APIのgetVoices()を以下のコードで実行したのですが、空の配列で返ってきます。どうすれば、取得できるのでしょうか。

```js
const voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
console.log(voice);

<･ []　//コンソールでの結果
```

ちなみに、ChromeはspeechSynthesisに対応していて、コンソールで上記のコードを実行すると、ちゃんと配列を返してくれます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`voiceschanged` イベントを待ってから実行しましょう。ページロード直後は声の用意ができていないことがあります。

```js
speechSynthesis.addEventListener('voiceschanged', e => {
  const voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  console.log(voice);
});
```